# Making my Office add-in more discoverable

Tags: office365, office-addins

I've created an Office add-in (a task pane in Word) that works te way I want it to and that I can distribute via the Office store. Once the add-in is installed however, it really isn't discoverable at all by users. A user as to deliberately go to add-ins and searh for the add-in to launch it. Are there ways to make my add-in more discoverable in the sense that it auto-launches or is pinned to the ribbon or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to achieve there are basically two options.

1. If the add-in accompanies a specific document you can actually save the document with the add-in opened to auto launch the add-in when a user opens that specific document.
2. Another way to achieve this is to add a so called add-in command (a ribbon button) to launch your task pane add-in. This gives your add-in a permanent place in the ribbon as long as it's installed. See the following for more info on how to do this: http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/design/add-in-commands

Answer (score 1):

It depends on you. Since an office add-in is something that you're hosting, you can advertise it on your website, go even further buy external ads from search engines saying you should try this etc..

You can also save a document with your add-in, share it with your friends so they would have it.